# SciTE: Showing the end of the output after execution

Tags: scite

I regularly use Scite for executing lengthy scripts (Batch files, python scripts).
Per default, the current position in the output window is set back to the start.
Is there some secret configuration option that instructs scite to just stop at the end of the output?
For my use case it would be more convenient that way, because I could see the end status right away without scrolling back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer via the [scite-interest](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/scite-interest) group:
It's right in the docs: http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html

> To stop the output pane from automatically scrolling, set output.scroll to 0. To have the 
>   output pane scroll and return back to the line of the executed
>   command, set output.scroll to 1. If you want the output pane to scroll
>   and remain at the bottom after execution, set output.scroll to 2.
>   The vertical scroll range is normally set so that maximum scroll
>   position has the last line at the bottom of the view. Set
>   end.at.last.line to 0 to allow scrolling one page below the last line.